# Custom URLs in post types make it impossible to view archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type (let's call it "video") and a custom taxonomy (let's call it "section"), I would like both of these to appear in the post URL.  The post URL rewriting is working fine. However, no matter what I do, the post type archive is a 404.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
register_post_type('video', array(
    // ..
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => "/%section%/video/",
     ),
     // ...
));

// this works
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_post_link', 1, 3);
function my_post_link($link, $id = 0)
{
    $post = get_post($id);
    $section = 'all';
    if (is_object($post)){
        if($terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'section')){
            $section = $terms[0]->slug;
        }
    }
    $link = str_replace('%section%', $section, $link);
   return $link;  
}

// this does not work
add_filter('post_type_archive_link', 'my_post_archive_link', 1, 3);
function my_post_archive_link($link, $id = 0)
{
    $link = str_replace('%section%', 'all', $link);
    return $link;  
}
```

Comment: The rewrite rule generated for the archive is just `video`. You can set that to a string instead of `true`, try `all/video`, though I'm not sure it'll work as it may clash with the rule for single videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using rewrite tags (dynamic values) in your slug, you don't have a "real" rewrite base for the archive URL. Instead of `true`, set it to something like `videos` & re-save your permalinks:

```
'has_archive' => 'videos',
```

...should give you a post type archive for `example.com/videos/`

Comment: You are my savior.  I spent all afternoon on this.  Thank you very much.